# Concatenet a string column grouping by another column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
   Name    Data
0  file1   a
1  file2   b
2  file1   c
3  file1   d
4  file2   e
```

I want to group by "Name" and concatenet the column "Data".

Output should look like this:

`file1  acd
file2  be`

I'm not able to figure it out how to do that. I can convert the dataframe into a list and then run a for loop and do it. But I'm trying to see if there's a better way to do it not using list.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `groupby` and `sum`:

```
print (df.groupby("Name").sum())

      Data
Name      
file1  acd
file2   be
```

Comment: Henry, if I want the output to look like this : "a,c,d" rather "acd"?

Comment: Then you to `apply` it: `df.groupby("Name").apply(lambda d: d["Data"].str.cat(sep=","))`, or `df.groupby("Name").apply(lambda d: ",".join(d["Data"]))`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: ''.join(x['Data']))` should get you there...check out group_concat in sql, you're looking to do exactly that